# Finding connected components using contours error in findContours function

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to find connected components using contour functions but I'm getting an error for findContours function. I'm using opencv 2.4.7 and visual studio 2010

```
    CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(img->height,img->width,CV_32FC3 );
    cvConvert( img, mat );
    CvMat *thr = cvCreateMat(img->height,img->width,CV_32FC3);
    cvCvtColor(mat,thr ,CV_RGBA2RGB);
    cvThreshold(thr, thr,25, 255,CV_THRESH_BINARY); //Threshold the gray
    int largest_area=0;
    int largest_contour_index=0;
    Rect bounding_rect;
    vector<vector<Point>> contours; // Vector for storing contour
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours( thr, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );         //Find the contours in the image
```

errors:

`IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point,     std::allocator<cv::Point>>, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point, std::allocator<cv::Point>>>>" to "CvMemStorage *" exists  c:\users\shahd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test_opencv\test_opencv\main.cpp   41`

`IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::vector<cv::Vec4i, std::allocator<cv::Vec4i>>" to "CvSeq **" exists    c:\users\shahd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test_opencv\test_opencv\main.cpp   41`

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code this is difficult so im spitballing...

Your second and third variables are of the wrong type

Comment: you're mixing outdated c-api calls with the c++ api. all your problems will go away, if you stick to the c++ api consistently, and avoid all cv*functions, CvMat* IplImage*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the datatype of your image is `Mat` which is used by **C++ type of openCV**. But the functions which you are using is of **C type openCV**.

So, instead of using `cvThreshold()`, try use `threshold()` as mentioned as this [**link**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold).

Comment: threshold() didn't work for me. Do you think that I should convert the mat to iplimage ?

Comment: Just stick to one format. Either use all the things related to `C type openCV` or `C++ type openCV`. It would be good if you put comment at each step of your code because i am really unable to understand what is your intention to do...for example i didn't understand why are you doing `cvConvert(img, mat);`..whether your `img` is of `IplImage*` or `Mat`. Similarly, i also don't understand why are you using `Mat*` for `thr`, why don't you use just `Mat`?